# Powershell weird error handling behavior

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I found a very weird thing about Powershell errors. Consider the following script:

```
function ProduceError {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param()
  #write-error a1
  #throw "a2"
  #a3.exe
}

function TestError {
  ProduceError -ea stop
  ProduceError -ea stop
}

TestError
```

I invoke the `ProduceError` cmdlet with a stop preference, so no matter whether a terminating or non-terminating error occurs, it should behave the same, but it doesn't.

This is what I'm observing with Powershell v3 (make sure a3.exe doesn't exist):

- Uncomment `write-error`: It will print a1 once and then stop.
- Uncomment `throw`: It will print a2 once and then stop.
- Uncomment `a3.exe`: It will complain **twice** about not finding a3.exe.

Why does calling a non-existent command seem to cause a non-terminating error, even if I set the error preference to stop? (I know I could set EA to stop inside `TestError`, but I want to know the cause of the inconsistency inside `ProduceError`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scoping issue, see [about_Scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx).

It's happening because you are implicitly using the call operator `&` when calling `a3.exe`. You can demonstrate this by changing your code to explicitly use it:

```powershell
function ProduceError {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param()
  & a3.exe
}
```

This will produce the same behavior. As the help page says:

> When you use the call operator (&) to run a function or script, it is not added to the current scope. The following example uses the call operator:

```powershell
& c:\scripts.sample.ps1
```

> Any aliases, functions, or variables that the Sample.ps1 script creates are not available in the current scope.

To get around that, you can use `Invoke-Expression` or `Start-Process`:

```powershell
function ProduceError {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param()
  Invoke-Expression a3.exe
}
```

or

```powershell
function ProduceError {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param()
  Start-Process a3.exe
}
```

These should work the way you expect, because the cmdlets are in your scope.

#### Edit based on your comment:

Using the call operator doesn't create a child scope (or subscope), it's a new session:

> Sessions, modules, and nested prompts are self-contained environments, but they are not child scopes of the global scope in the session.
>
> Sessions:
>   A session is an environment in which Windows PowerShell runs. When you create a session on a remote computer, Windows PowerShell establishes a persistent connection to the remote computer. The persistent connection lets you use the session for multiple related commands.
>
> Because a session is a contained environment, it has its own scope, but a session is not a child scope of the session in which is was created. The session starts with its own global scope. This scope is independent of the global scope of the session. You can create child scopes in the session. For example, you can run a script to create a child scope in a session.

Comment: I believe you that this is the cause, but I still don't get it. EA should be Stop inside ProduceError's scope, and all subscopes should inherit that setting. But even if there is another scope in there, how can a non-terminating error get out out of ProduceError? Or does error handling work differently on scope boundaries?

Comment: So you're saying that EA Stop is not inherited when executing a3.exe? So even if EA is Stop inside ProduceError, it doesn't turn a non-terminating error into a terminating one from the call operation? That seems inconsistent, I imagined that EA Stop means that no non-terminating errors will escape from ProduceError, but apparently they do. In that case, how to make sure that calling a non-existent file, or a non-existent function, ends up in a terminating error?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It seems inconsistent, but essentially, the error that's "escaping" is really just being returned as the result. The calling and called session can't affect the flow of the other. To make sure you have a terminating error, use the methods in my answer (`Invoke-Expression` or `Start-Process`), and/or use `Test-Path` to make sure your exe exists before executing.